# NuxtJS and event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create an event from an instance property in nuxt, however the event is not emitted or received.

`plugins/internal/bus.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const eventBus = {}

eventBus.install = function (Vue) {
  Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue()
}

Vue.use(eventBus)
```

`plugins/internal/index.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function (_ctx, inject) {
  const notify  = function (msg) {

    console.log('emitting', msg);

    setInterval(() => {
      this.$bus.$emit('add', msg);
    }, 500);
  }
   .bind(new Vue());

  inject('notify', notify);
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/internal/bus.js',
    '~/plugins/internal/index.js',
    ...
  ]
```

And in my component,

```js
  mounted() {
    this.$bus.$on('add', (val) => {
      console.log(val);
    })
    this.$bus.$on('close', this.onClose)
  },
```

Doing `this.$notify({ foo: 'bar' })`, calls the instance property correctly, however either the event is not emitted or is not received, frankly not sure how to debug this. What am I missing here?

Comment: To debug this, use the Vue devtools. You'll be able to see what is emitted. Btw, why are you using an event bus? Vuex is cleaner and simpler to track (hence debug). Your code seems quite complex, is there a reason? If your issue cannot be solved with Vuex, I might link you a talk/article explaining how you could achieve it properly in Nuxt.

Comment: Well, I was going to try with Vuex next, though I wouldn't mind taking a look at the said article.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/0z69RXxJpcU) and [this article](https://deltener.com/blog/nuxt-third-party-code-is-poison/).

Comment: Thank you, will take a look. 
I couldn't find much about using Vuex to dispatch some sort of an event, do have some resources on that?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions) is still the best place to go.

Comment: Thank you, though the solution to this was very stupid..I had forgot to register the `Notification` component..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, the issue was coming from a component (`Notification`) that was not properly registered.